# Function return value in constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In Javascript functions can be arguments of a constructor but I would like to assign a conditional value to be evaluated when a new object is created.

```
var obj = {
  prop: function(){ return 1; },
  prop2: "asd"
};

console.log(obj.prop);  // This prints "function() ..."
```

With this method, Is there any way to make prop value 1 ?

For those of you wondering why I want to do this, I have the following code and I need to pass a different offset parameter if some condition is true or not.

```
$('#primary-menu > ul > li > a[href*=#]').smoothScroll(


{ preventDefault: true, easing: 'swing', speed: 700, offset: -200, exclude: ['.external a'],
    beforeScroll: function () {

        // Disable all waypoints on internal divs which are linked to from the menu
        $('#primary-menu > ul > li > a[href*=#]').each(function () {
            var element_id = MO_THEME.get_internal_link($(this).attr('href')); // Gives me ids of div's with ids like #work,#service, #portfolio etc.
            $(element_id).waypoint('disable');
        });
    },
    afterScroll: function () {
        // Enable all waypoints on internal divs which are linked to from the menu
        $('#primary-menu > ul > li > a[href*=#]').each(function () {
            var element_id = MO_THEME.get_internal_link($(this).attr('href')); // Gives me ids of div's with ids like #work,#service, #portfolio etc.
            $(element_id).waypoint('enable');
        });
    }});
```

Comment: Can't you call `console.log(obj.prop());` instead?

Comment: Do you mean you want the `offset` to be variable when you instantiate the `smoothScroll` or you want `offset` to change after instantiating `smootScroll`?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: Do you mean you want the offset to be variable when you instantiate the smoothScroll or you want offset to change after instantiating smootScroll?

Ideally I would pass the correct offset value when calling the constructor, but this value is variable, so what I would want is to assign to offset the value, (in my prev example , prop should value 1, not function () )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change any of the options of the [`smoothScroll` plugin after instantiation](https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll):

> ### Setting options after initial call
>
> If you need to change any of the options after you've already called `.smoothScroll()`, you can do so by passing the "options" string as the first argument and an options object as the second.

```
$el.smoothScroll('options', {
  offset: newValue
});
```

Comment: I think with this it's solved, however I would like to know if that "dirty" property declaration is possible in javascript

Comment: @Msam85 It is not possible.